# Wordpress Pop Up box plugin

Tags: email, facebook, wordpress

I'm looking for a WordPress plugin that will pop up a small box when a user shares a post, exactly like the one on the articles at lifebuzz.com. I'd like it to have the same information on the pop up; a facebook 'like' button and an e-mail newsletter sign-up. I currently use MailChip for newsletters so ideally I'd like it to be compatible.

Here's a screenshot of the pop up I'm looking for from lifebuzz:

[image: lifebuzz popup]